# Change size of foreign key widget in django admin

Tags: python, css, django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I've spent the last two days trying to do this, and I can't figure it out.  I'm using grappelli, and I've tried several things.

I tried specifying the widget:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        widgets = {
            'foreign_key': widgets.TextInput(attrs={'width': '200'}),
        }
```

In this case, it just seemed to be ignored.

I also tried adding css using a `Media` definition.  This got loaded, but inspecting the element in my browse showed that it was overridden by the grappelli css.

Is there an easy way of doing this that I've missed?

Comment: Are you sure the name of the field is foreign_key?

Comment: @catherine No, its not.  That's just an example using generic names, but I did check that it was correct in my actual code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would re-try adding css using the media definition but this time, put a `!important` to your css attribute.

```
.widget input {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

From http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets/Important

> The important keyword makes a declaration take precedence over normal
>   declarations—those that are not tagged with the important keyword. So
>   "p { color: red ! important }" takes precedence over "p { color: green
>   }".